# Buildroot - move to another machine make failed

Tags: buildroot

I have a following problem: due to my computer breakdown I had to move whole buildroot system to another machine and put it in another directory.It stoped to compile. I tried "make clean" and "make all" but it gave no effect. Could anyone tell me what might be the reason and how to fix it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Save your **.config** file, and do a `make mrproper`

Answer (score 1):

It is true that Buildroot currently doesn't support moving to another location, because some of the binaries generated during the build will have absolute paths embedded in them. However, with "make clean; make" it should be resolved, because that removes and rebuilds all binaries.

You can look for help on the mailing list or on IRC, as [documented in the manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#community-resources).